# How to make every file accessible without a express route assigned to it

Tags: node.js, express

Is it to possible to make every single file accessible without a express route assigned to it? For example with a normal static website you are able to create an html file and have it accessible at domain.com/blah.html but with express I have to actually create a route to be able to see the html view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put them in a folder at the root level of the project and serve them.

Let say you made a folder called public, in your app.js file (where app here is the express instance) add this line.

`app.use(express.static('public'))`

Now anything you have in there will be accessible if you go to domain.com/blah.html

Answer (score 0):

[Serving Static files](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) might help.

Answer (score 0):

When using express i.e. a js package as backend, you will need to define a route to access the frontend files. It's like an address, you don't have the address, the program can't find the file and hence can't display it. For example:

```
    app.get("/", function(req, res) {
       res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
    });
```

This is when you need to access the root route to access your index.html file. Another example, where you need to access the "about" page:

```
    app.get("/about", function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + "/about.html"); 
    });
```

Note that each time I have defined a relative path to access the files.

Comment: The question was serving a static file without routes setup. Your answer does not help.